# Episerver Scheduled Job Daylight Savings

Tags: episerver

It seems that EPiServer 7.1 automatically adjusts the set time in scheduled jobs according to daylight savings. Since the server usually does this we don't need EPiServer to do it as well. Is there a way to disable this feature?

Comment: I'm not aware of EPiServer doing anything other than going by the server (i.e. Windows) time?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Although, I have stumbled upon others with the same issue: http://world.episerver.com/Forum/Developer-forum/EPiServer-CMS-6-R2/Thread-Container/2012/11/Daylight-Savings/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could do something like the following in an **InitializableModule** when the site starts?

```
var repo = new ScheduledJobRepository();

var scheduledJob = repo.List().First(job => job.Name.Equals("My scheduled job"));

// Set some relevant UTC time, irrelevant of daylight savings time
scheduledJob.NextExecution = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToUniversalTime();

repo.Save(scheduledJob);
```

Never tried it myself, but might be worth a shot? :)

**Edit:** In previous EPiServer versions, you could iterate over scheduled jobs like this:

```
ScheduledJobCollection jobs = ScheduledJob.List();

foreach (ScheduledJob job in jobs)
{
   Response.Write(job.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you mean. I will give it a try.

Comment: Good luck! Let me know how it pans out. :)

Comment: It seems the ScheduledJobRepository is a feature in CMS 7.8. I think we use 7.0 or something like that. Do you know of another way of listing all jobs? I tried using the ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance, but don't know which type to use. Any idea?

Comment: I don't have access to a pre-7.5 site currently, so I can't test it. But perhaps you could use the ScheduledJob class?